# Forcing the update of a JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

When I edit the quantity of an object in a list and the toString changes, how do I get the list to update with the new toString?

Example, when I change nodes in my JTree, I use nodeChanged(node) what do I do when I change a list item?

Comment: The only thing that seemed apparent is updateUI.

Comment: updateUI is a method on the `JList`, while you should have been searching on the model side (and not the view side)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`AbstractListModel#fireContentsChanged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html#fireContentsChanged%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) if you extend from `AbstractListModel`.

It is the same principle as for the `JTree` of your previous question. The `AbstractListModel` does not know when some internal property of your objects is changed. So when you make a change, you must call that particular method indicating the object is changed. The list model will fire the correct event which is received by the `JList`, which will update/repaint (whatever you want to call it).

Personally I prefer to create `ListModel`s which are self-contained, e.g. if the objects you use fire events when they change the `ListModel` can listen for those changes and fire the appropriate events itself instead of having to call this method externally.

*Edit*

Just noticed that that particular method is protected, so you need to create the model as I suggested and you cannot call that method externally (which is a good thing)

Comment: AbstractListModel#fireContentsChanged :-) , I can share my recharger for your battery :-), just my curiosity can you please to elaborate :-)

Comment: most times you have got very good ideas, in this case I have got originally an idea that you suggested to sharing JTree model for  JList, then my question

Comment: No, I wanted to refer to his question which I answered 5 minutes before this question which was the exact same question but only for a `JTree` instead of a `JList`

Comment: Hmm. So you can't really do it if you're using a `DefaultListModel` then. I find it cumbersome to have to extend it just to expose that method (or write an equivalent)...

Answer (score 0):

List.updateUI() will do it, although I'm told this has some overhead.

Comment: not use updateUI, those methods are [for Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)

Comment: *"I will accept any other answers."*  In those cases, perhaps best left as a comment.

Comment: Well, I know that updateUI will do what I want, but I've heard it's very wrong.

Comment: @mKorbel Would `repaint()` be better? (it also works but doesn't seem related to LaF).

Comment: @Matthieu there must be something wrong coded, because JList haven't any issue to repaint all changes from methods implemented in API, in the case that all updates are done on EDT, wrapped into invokeLater() for example (not the void, class, ... creates output to Swing GUI, but concrete method impemented in JList API)